# Moving Through Records Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a list of names in a subform, and on my main form I have a button that allows the user to view the "profile" of a given contact. Once in a profile, I would like there to be a button that allows the user to move to the next name in the subform (while staying the "profile" view) by clicking "next user".

In addition, the DB asks the user whether she/he wants to save changes (vbYesNo) to the profile before moving to the next user's profile. For some reason, my code works the when the user clicks "next contact" and "yes" the first time, but it will not scroll to the next contact each subsequent time the user clicks "next contact" and "yes". Note that the "next user" button works fine if the user selects "no" for when she/he does not want to save changes made to the profile.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Command65_Click()

Dim strFirstName As String
Dim strLastName As String
Dim strIndustry As String
Dim strCountry As String
Dim strState As String
Dim strCity As String
Dim strCompany As String
Dim strTitle As String
Dim strStatus As String
Dim strPhone As String
Dim strEmail As String
Dim strOwner As String
Dim DateNow As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

'Allow user to leave some fields blank. User must fill in certain fields.

Dim VisEnable

intMsg = MsgBox("Would you like to save the current contact's information?", vbYesNo)

If intMsg = 6 Then

If IsNull(Me.txtFirstName) Then
    MsgBox ("Please add First Name for this Prospect")
    Me.txtFirstName.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

If IsNull(Me.txtLastName) Then
    MsgBox ("Please add Last Name for this Prospect")
    Me.txtLastName.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

If IsNull(Me.cboIndustry) Then
    Me.cboIndustry = ""
    Exit Sub
End If

If IsNull(Me.cboGeo) Then
    Me.cboGeo = ""
End If

If IsNull(Me.cboInfluence) Then
    Me.cboInfluence = ""
End If

If IsNull(Me.cboSchool) Then
    Me.cboSchool = ""
End If
If IsNull(Me.cboTier) Then
    Me.cboTier = ""
End If
If IsNull(Me.cboCompany) Then
    Me.cboCompany = ""
End If

If IsNull(Me.txtTitle) Then
    Me.txtTitle = ""
End If

If IsNull(Me.cboStatus) Then
    Me.cboStatus = ""
    Exit Sub
End If

If IsNull(Me.cboOwner) Then
    Me.cboOwner = ""
End If

If IsNull(Me.txtPhone) Then
    Me.txtPhone = ""
End If

If IsNull(Me.txtEmail) Then
    MsgBox ("Please add Email for this Prospect")
    Me.txtEmail.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

If IsNull(Me.txtNotes) Then
    Me.txtNotes = ""
    Exit Sub
End If

If IsNull(Me.txtInitialProspectEmailSentDate) Then
Me.txtInitialProspectEmailSentDate = ""
End If

If IsNull(Me.txtNextTouchPoint) Then
Me.txtNextTouchPoint = ""
End If

strFirstName = Me.txtFirstName
strLastName = Me.txtLastName
strIndustry = Me.cboIndustry
strCompany = Me.cboCompany
strTitle = Me.txtTitle
strStatus = Me.cboStatus
strPhone = Me.txtPhone
strEmail = Me.txtEmail
strNotes = Me.txtNotes
strOwner = Me.cboOwner
dtEmailSent = Me.txtInitialProspectEmailSentDate
dtNextTouchPoint = Me.txtNextTouchPoint
strRegion = Me.cboGeo
strSoR = Me.cboTier
strInfluence = Me.cboInfluence
strClient = Me.ckClient
strCoworker = Me.ckCoworker
strSchool = Me.cboSchool

strSQL = "Update tblProspect Set FirstName = " & """" & strFirstName & """" & ",LastName = " & """" & strLastName & """" & ",Industry = " & """" & strIndustry & """" & "" & _
",Geography = " & """" & strRegion & """" & ",StrengthofRelationship = " & """" & strSoR & """" & ",School = " & """" & strSchool & """" & ",Company = " & """" & strCompany & """" & "" & _
",Title = " & """" & strTitle & """" & ",Status = " & """" & strStatus & """" & ", InfluenceLevel = " & """" & strInfluence & """" & ", FormerClient = " & strClient & ", FormerCoWorker = " & strCoworker & "" & _
",Email = " & """" & strEmail & """" & ",Phone = " & """" & strPhone & """" & ",ProspectOwner = " & """" & strOwner & """" & ",Notes = " & """" & strNotes & """" & ""


If dtNextTouchPoint <> "" Then
strSQL = strSQL & " ,NextTouchPoint = #" & dtNextTouchPoint & "#"
End If

If dtEmailSent <> "" Then
strSQL = strSQL & " ,LastEmailDate = #" & dtEmailSent & "#"
End If
strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE Email = " & """" & strEmail & """" & ""
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
DoCmd.SetWarnings True


intRecord = Me.txtRecord + 1

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("qselProspects")
    If rs.RecordCount <> 0 Then
    rs.MoveLast
    If intRecord = 1 Then
    intRecord = rs.RecordCount + 1
    End If
    End If

    If rs.RecordCount <> 0 Then
    rs.MoveFirst 'Unnecessary in this case, but still a good habit
    Do Until rs.EOF = True

    If intRecord = rs.AbsolutePosition Then

            Me.txtRecord = intRecord
            Me.txtFirstName = rs!FirstName
            Me.txtLastName = rs!LastName
            Me.txtTitle = rs!Title
            Me.cboCompany = rs!Company
            Me.cboIndustry = rs!Industry
            Me.cboGeo = rs!Geography
            Me.cboTier = rs!StrengthofRelationship
            Me.cboIndustry = rs!InfluenceLevel
            Me.cboSchool = rs!School
            Me.ckClient = rs!FormerClient
            Me.ckCoworker = rs!FormerCoWorker
            Me.cboStatus = rs!Status
            Me.cboOwner = rs!ProspectOwner
            Me.txtEmail = rs!Email
            Me.txtPhone = rs!Phone
            Me.txtNextTouchPoint = rs!NextTouchPoint
            Me.txtNotes = rs!Notes
            Me.txtInitialProspectEmailSentDate = rs!LastEmailDate

            End If
     rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End If

'''///If you choose No it works, but if you choose Yes it does not...very strange
Else

intRecord = Me.txtRecord + 1

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("qselProspects")
    If rs.RecordCount <> 0 Then
    rs.MoveLast
    If rs.RecordCount = intRecord Then
    intRecord = 0
    End If
    End If

    If rs.RecordCount <> 0 Then
    rs.MoveFirst 
    Do Until rs.EOF = True

            If intRecord = rs.AbsolutePosition Then

            Me.txtRecord = intRecord
            Me.txtFirstName = rs!FirstName
            Me.txtLastName = rs!LastName
            Me.txtTitle = rs!Title
            Me.cboCompany = rs!Company
            Me.cboIndustry = rs!Industry
            Me.cboGeo = rs!Geography
            Me.cboTier = rs!StrengthofRelationship
            Me.cboIndustry = rs!InfluenceLevel
            Me.cboSchool = rs!School
            Me.ckClient = rs!FormerClient
            Me.ckCoworker = rs!FormerCoWorker
            Me.cboStatus = rs!Status
            Me.cboOwner = rs!ProspectOwner
            Me.txtEmail = rs!Email
            Me.txtPhone = rs!Phone
            Me.txtNextTouchPoint = rs!NextTouchPoint
            Me.txtNotes = rs!Notes
            Me.txtInitialProspectEmailSentDate = rs!LastEmailDate

            End If

     rs.MoveNext
    Loop

End If
End If
End Sub
```

Thanks to whoever can figure this out! This has eaten up too many hours as it is.

Comment: Looks like quite a bit of code for UI commands also available in macros: `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord` and `DoCmd.GoTorecord , , acNext`. Might want to share why you run updates and open recordsets.

Comment: In the validation-looking bit, you've got some Exit Subs without any `MsgBox` to say why the sub is being exited. E.g. when you test `If IsNull(Me.txtLastName) Then...` you give a message of "Please add Last Name for this Prospect" and then exit the sub (which is fine). Then the next `If` tests `cboIndustry` for null and then just exits the sub with no explanation to the user. So when you are testing this, is the validation picking up these null fields with no message box and kicking you out of the sub without giving you a clue why?

Comment: Thanks guys, all good advice!

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but I write it here because it does not fit in a comment. A few advises that if you have applied, would have spared you all this head-ache.

1) your code follows the pattern

```
If User_Says_Yes Then
   Save
   Fetch_Next_Record
Else
   Fetch_Next_Record
Endif
```

This is problematic because the Fetch_Next_Record is a lot of code and it is duplicated, and you spend a lot of time to see where it differs. duplicating code is generally a very bad idea. Try to rewrite it with the following pattern:

```
If User_Says_Yes Then
   Save
Endif
Fetch_Next_Record
```

2) Try to make your code shorter, by moving as much as you can to private subroutines. for example, write some Function like `BuildSQL() as String`, a subroutine like `updateFormFromRs(rs as Recordset)`. In General, when any of your routines or functions get too long, say more than 20 or 30 lines, you should think of migrating some code to subroutines and functions

3) Indent your code. It is so difficult to follow your code without it.. just to see where was the Else that starts when the user says no...

4) You fetch a whole table in the recordset, just to scroll it and find one record to display that matches `if intRecord = rs.AbsolutePosition`? Why not use a SQL statement with a `WHERE` clause and load just the desired record? This is something you *need* to apply in any serious application with a decent amount of data.

5) statements like `If rs.EOF = True Then`: Simply `If rs.EOF Then`.
The additional `= True` will not make the test more strict whatsoever. as if without it we check if the condition was *almost true*.

Finally, even if you have possibly inherited this code from someone else, I am sure that you will have to rewrite it completely and improve it, the sooner the better. And yes, I am sure that if you follow these guidelines, you will be able to debug you code very easily.

Friendly :)

Comment: The comments are very valid. Except that also I would recommend a complete rewrite, you could save _a bunch_ of code using Nz, for example: `strFirstName = Nz(Me.txtFirstName)`.